# Removing a value from R

Tags: r

Is there a way to remove specific values using `R` programming?

For example, I have a variable named `Survive`. This variable has input values such as `"Y"`, `"N"`, and `"U"`. Is there a code to remove all the `"U"` values?

I am fairly new to `R` and tried this code:

```
project$Survive = "U"<-NULL
```

which obviously did not work.

Comment: Do you want `project$Survive[project$Survive == "U"] <- NA` ? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible soutions. One filtering (dropping) observations where `Survive` is  "U" and the other just transforming to a missing value (`NA`) using the package `dplyr`. I would encourage looking at the package {dplyr}, which has a quite intuitive interface for data manipulation.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

project <- tribble(
  ~id, ~Survive, ~value, 
  1,      "A",     42,
  1,      "U",     31,
  2,      "A",     21,
  2,      "U",     11
)

project %>% 
  # filter (keep) observations where survive is not equal to "U". 
  filter(Survive != "U")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>      id Survive value
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1     1 A          42
#> 2     2 A          21


project %>% 
  # mutate "U" into character missing (NA) when Survive == "U". 
  mutate(Survive = if_else(Survive == "U", NA_character_, Survive))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      id Survive value
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1     1 A          42
#> 2     1 <NA>       31
#> 3     2 A          21
#> 4     2 <NA>       11


# base R approach for keeping a subset of observations.
(res_project <- subset(project, Survive != "U"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>      id Survive value
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1     1 A          42
#> 2     2 A          21
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>